# Prove correctness of in-order tree traversal subroutine

Tags: algorithms, induction, binary-search-trees

I'm trying to prove that in-order tree traversal prints the keys in sorted order. It's shown [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12610/question-about-the-formal-proof-of-the-inorder-traversing), but what I want is to prove correctness using ordinary induction.

> Claim: For any n-node  subtree, the in-order-tree-walk subroutine prints the keys of the subtree rooted at node x in sorted order.

```
in-order-tree-walk(x)
  if(x!=NIL)
    in-order-tree-walk(x.left)
    print x.key
    in-order-tree-walk(x.right)
```

Above pseudo-code is taken from [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844), and we're traversing the subtree rooted at node x.

> Proof.
> By ordinary induction. Let our induction hypothesis $P(n)$ be the claim itself. We need show $P(n)$ holds for all positive integers.
> Base case ($n=1$):
> In-order-tree-walk subroutine prints the single node's key and, since the both *left* and *right* pointers are *NIL*, terminates. Trivially, single key is already in sorted order.
> Inductive step:
> Suppose $P(n)$ holds for some $n \geq 1$. Prove $P(n+1)$. Let $T$ be subtree consisting of $n+1$ nodes. Let $T'$ be subtree formed by removing the largest element from $T$. $T'$ has $n$ elements. By induction hypothesis $P(n)$, *in-order-tree-walk(T')* prints keys of subtree rooted at *T'.root* in sorted order. By binary-search-tree property, largest element in the tree is placed on the rightmost node and it's the last node visited during the in-order-tree traversal. So, that rightmost node's key is printed after the keys of $T'$ is printed. Since it's the largest element in $T$, and keys of $T'$ in printed in sorted order, we can conclude that *in-order-tree-walk(T')* prints keys of $T$ in sorted order.
> By induction principle, we can conclude that $P(n)$ holds for all positive integers.

Can we show correctness using this induction proof?
Is any parts of the proof need to be revised?

I appreciate your efforts.

EDIT: Trees/subtrees in this post refer to binary search trees. Binary search tree property is preassumed.

Comment: You should state clearly in you hypothesis that the tree is a BST. Also, it may be easier to make the induction not on the sizes of the trees, but on the trees themselves. The inductive step would be "Suppose $T = Node(a, k, b)$ a BST where $P(a)$ and $P(b)$ holds, then…"

Answer (score 1):

In your proof the largest element of binary search tree $T$ can in fact be the root of the tree. I did not check whether you took care of that.

If you want to use induction by a number of elements in the tree, I would advise you to take *strong induction*, that is the hypothesis assumes the algorithm works for *any* number less or equal to $n$. Then the hypothesis can be applied to both subtrees which must have less elements than the full tree.

Finaly you could use *structural induction*, that is induction using the inductive definition of the structures you consider. Here that is the notion of a binary tree: which is either empty, or a root and two subtrees. In practise this gives the same proof as strong induction, but you did not need to quantify the number of nodes.